# Change color of LineChartData label

Tags: ios, ios-charts

[LineChartView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdmtj.png)
I have a `LineChartView` which I am displaying over a black background.

I have everything showing up as I want, except the label which I use when I create the dataset does not appear.

I assume this is due to the black `background` as it does appear if I change the background to white. is there any way to set the color of this `label`? Thank you.

Comment: Still issue is there ? if Yes Please provide image or more description so we can help you out.

Comment: Here is the image. Note that the blue square under the chart appears but not the label. lineChart.png

Comment: Where is your image ? please add image into your question.

Comment: Sorry, having trouble including the image. I've done so by Answer'ing the question, hopefully that will have the link to the uploaded image.

Comment: Ok I've edited the question and added a link to the image. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this issue?

Comment: Sorry I have found the solution, I must set the lineChartView.legend.textColor to white if I have a black background. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you need to change a property of Legend of chart view right after a chartView configuration.

```
chartView.legend.textColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing like this you can change color of label text:

```
var charts = LineChartView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        charts.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.darkGray

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
chartView.data = data
chartView.data?.setValueTextColor(NSUIColor.white)
```